# PHP Session expiring and system force logout

Tags: session-timeout

When i left system is in idle mode( means inactive mode) , and when i come to access system after 1 or 2 hours, system reacts well when i use single window but when i generate recieppt through ajax and open the receipt in window.popup window then the system logs out. and redirect to login page because session expired in idle mode , even if i set the session for lifetime,

```
case '1':
        $_SESSION['kid'] = $q4['id'];
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 100*60*60);
        session_set_cookie_params(0,"/");
break;
```

plese help ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', ...)` should be called **before** `session_start()`

Comment: thnx , but session_start is in connection.php . is it valid i put ini set in connection.php

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind it always accounts for all session values